# How to programmatically build VIs without user interaction?

Tags: deployment, build, labview

I have a LabVIEW project with five cRIO targets. I wrote a build VI that compiles and deploys the rtexes, after the deployment the target is rebooted. The problem is that while deploying, LabVIEW opens a connection to the target that it wants to keep alive. That is why it displays an error dialog that says "Warning: Connection to target (name) has been lost." 
The question now is what do I have to do to supress these dialogs or how can I write it that they are avoided totally?

[image: Start the build for every RT if the button is pressed]
[image: Build, deploy, clean and reboot]

**EDIT:**
I want to build or compile the buildspecifications, I don't want to generate any code. The problem is that if LabVIEW connects to a cRIO it keeps the connection alive and when restarting it, it cannot reconnect because it would stop the executed rtexe so it pops up an error which I don't know how to supress or get rid of it. The restart has to be done that the built rtexe is executed.

[image: The unwanted popup]

**EDIT 2**
The problem is that this popup blocks the execution of the following code. It should be a silent VI without popups. The replication software is not the right choice because the code differs from target to target.

Comment: Your question is not fully clear to me, but can you not just simply suppress the warning? Furthermore your title implies that you want to create VI's automatically? If that is the case, take a look over here, http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209110

Comment: I edited my question I hope it is clearer now what I try to do.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear to me. Can you please describe? why you don't want to use NI replication software at all?

Comment: Please see my second edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have the cRIOs added to your project. Interesting that a deploy will automatically connect but not disconnect.

One possibility is to disable the automatic connection check in the project properties of the cRIO.

The other possibility is having LabVIEW disconnect from all targets. See screenshot below. Basically you iterate through all devices of all open projects and disconnect from them. You'd have to do this after every deploy.

[image: Disconnecting from all connected targets in LabVIEW]

[Sorry, only german LabVIEW available here]